# lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), x)

Tags: c++, vector, lower-bound

I am a noob to c++, I just came across this code

```
       x = v[lft]+k;
       low = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), x) - v.begin();

       if(low >= n|| v[low] > x )
        low--;
       center = v[low];
```

if x is not present in the vector, it returns a value greater than the size of the vector. That justifies searching whether `low >= n` , but I cant figure out under which circumstance will this condition  `v[low] > x` satisy?Should'nt `low` be an index in which x is present, so how can there be a value greater than x?

Comment: This question must have been asked around a thousand times just in SO!

Comment: From the documentation of [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) : *"Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first, last) that is **not less** than (i.e. greater or equal to) value."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lower_bound` returns

> an **iterator** pointing to the first element in the range `[first, last)` that is **not less than** (i.e. **greater or equal to**) value.

See here for more detail: [lower_bound - cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)